# Returning Delta Results from Serverless SQL Select Statements returns Invalid Object error

Tags: sql, serverless, azure-synapse, delta-lake

I am working through the samples in this document from Microsoft. [Linux Foundation Delta Lake overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-delta-lake-overview?pivots=programming-language-python#save-as-catalog-tables)

The sections on table creation work of Notebooks works in that I have tables created in the default database as expected in accordance with the samples.

I have also created a delta table in another Lake Database that I have previously created.  This too is successful using

```
%%sql
CREATE TABLE avsales.creditcardDelta
USING DELTA 
LOCATION '/delta/delta-table-703038'
```

If I try to query this in the notebook I get good results

```
%%pyspark
df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM `avsales`.`creditcarddelta`")
df.show(10)
```

| CreditCardID | CardType | CardNumber | ExpMonth | ExpYear | ModifiedDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SuperiorCard | 33332664695310 | 11 | 2006 | 2013-07-29 00:00:... |
| 2 | Distinguish | 55552127249722 | 8 | 2005 | 2013-12-05 00:00:... |
| 3 | ColonialVoice | 77778344838353 | 7 | 2005 | 2014-01-14 00:00:... |
| 4 | ColonialVoice | 77774915718248 | 7 | 2006 | 2013-05-20 00:00:... |
| 5 | Vista | 11114404600042 | 4 | 2005 | 2013-02-01 00:00:... |
| 6 | Distinguish | 55557132036181 | 9 | 2006 | 2014-04-10 00:00:... |
| 7 | Distinguish | 55553635401028 | 6 | 2007 | 2013-02-01 00:00:... |
| 8 | SuperiorCard | 33336081193101 | 7 | 2007 | 2013-06-30 00:00:... |
| 9 | Distinguish | 55553465625901 | 2 | 2005 | 2013-09-23 00:00:... |
| 10 | SuperiorCard | 33332126386493 | 8 | 2008 | 2011-08-31 00:00:... |

However if I try to run a SQL script on the table I get an error.

```
SELECT TOP (10) [CreditCardID]
,[CardType]
,[CardNumber]
,[ExpMonth]
,[ExpYear]
,[ModifiedDate]
 FROM [avsales].[dbo].[creditcarddelta]
```

returns

```
Started executing query at Line 1
Invalid object name 'avsales.dbo.creditcarddelta'.
Total execution time: 00:00:02.307
```

This is true of any SQL from default as well.

Has anyone managed to get this to work?  If so what did I miss?

Comment: Remove `.[dbo].` and see what happens.

Comment: That syntax is invalid for example this query of a parquet table in the same database returns values correctly:
```
SELECT TOP (100) [CountryRegionCode]
,[CurrencyCode]
,[ModifiedDate]
,[_corrupt_record]
 FROM [avsales].[dbo].[countryregioncurrency]
```

Comment: Still a bit odd . You create the table `avsales.creditcardDelta`,and when you select from the table `[avsales].[dbo].[creditcarddelta]` -  you get the error _Invalid object name 'avsales.dbo.creditcarddelta'_.

Comment: so.. what error do you get when you run `SELECT * FROM avsales.creditcarddelta`?

Comment: The error I get is Invalid object name 'avsales.creditcarddelta' but similarly I get  Invalid object name 'avsales.countryregioncurrency'. where as this works SELECT TOP (100) *
 FROM [avsales].[dbo].[countryregioncurrency]

Comment: @jarlh its not odd its the difference between sparksql and SQL.  This is pretty well documented and honestly a distraction.